# Tab Bar scroll to the top of UIViewController when pressed twice

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm trying to make my `UITabBarController` scroll to the top of the page when pressed twice. I have tried several times to get this to work with no luck. As of now, I only have one class for the `UITabBarController` on the storyboard that is linked to the code. Am I supposed to link `UITabBar` as well? Here's my code that I've attempted so far.

```
  import UIKit

class TabViewController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    var pressedCount: Int = 0


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    @IBAction func unwindToMain(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {}

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        print("Selected item")
    }

    // UITabBarControllerDelegate
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        print("Selected view controller")
    }
    func tabBarController(_ TabViewController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        guard let viewControllers = viewControllers else { return false }
        if viewController == viewControllers[selectedIndex] {
            if let nav = viewController as? UINavigationController {
                guard let topController = nav.viewControllers.last else { return true }
                if !topController.isScrolledToTop {
                    topController.scrollToTop()
                    return false
                } else {
                    nav.popViewController(animated: true)
                }
                return true
            }
        }

        return true
    }
}


extension UIViewController {
    func scrollToTop() {
        func scrollToTop(view: UIView?) {
            guard let view = view else { return }

            switch view {
            case let scrollView as UIScrollView:
                if scrollView.scrollsToTop == true {
                    scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: -scrollView.contentInset.top), animated: true)
                    return
                }
            default:
                break
            }

            for subView in view.subviews {
                scrollToTop(view: subView)
            }
        }

        scrollToTop(view: view)
    }

    var isScrolledToTop: Bool {
        if self is UITableViewController {
            return (self as! UITableViewController).tableView.contentOffset.y == 0
        }
        for subView in view.subviews {
            if let scrollView = subView as? UIScrollView {
                return (scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0)
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
   var pressedCount: Int = 0

   func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {

    pressedCount += 1
    if pressedCount > 1 {
        scrollToTop(view: self.view)
        } else {
        //do something for first press
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do I make a new controller for UITabBar or do I implement this into the rest of my code

Comment: try typing in func tabBarController(_ and look for didSelectItem

Comment: if you know how to call an action if the tab bar is pressed once just use this code to increment on that action.

Comment: I've edited my code and I can now track when the tab bar is pressed, where would I implement your code

Comment: inside the function where the tab bar is pressed add 
 pressedCount += 1
    if pressedCount > 1 {
        scrollToTop(view: self.view)
        } else {
        //do something for first press
        }
    }

Comment: Getting the error "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments" on the scrollToTop line

Comment: you have two different functions named scrollToTop?

Answer (score 0):

Customize the UITabBar and then use the notification time to make the outside world respond!Or record the number of clicks through the UITabBarController agent and then notify the outside world to respond!

Comment: A little new to coding, could you give me an example of this?